# Azure Powershell Script is ignoring defaultValue

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I am using PowerShell ISE to recreate an existing database using the script generated in the Azure Portal for the resource. I discovered that PS, does not use the script path, so I added these lines at the top:

```
Write-Host $PSScriptRoot
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot
Write-Host "Path: $(get-location)"
```

I added some testing code to make sure the template.json and parameters.json are present and that is working:

```
# Start the deployment
Write-Host "Starting deployment...";
Write-Host "Testing: $templateFilePath"
if(Test-Path $templateFilePath) {
    Write-Host "FOUND: $templateFilePath"

    if(Test-Path $parametersFilePath) {
        Write-Host "FOUND: $parametersFilePath"
        New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $templateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $parametersFilePath;
    } else {
        New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $templateFilePath;
    }

}
```

However, the script is still ignoring the defaultValue parameters in template.json:

```
"advisors_DropIndex_name": {
    "defaultValue": "DropIndex",
    "type": "String"
},
```

parameters.json:

```
"advisors_DropIndex_name": {
    "value": null
},
```

The script returns the following:

*New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 5:17:30 PM - Error: Code=InvalidDeploymentParameterValue; Message=The value of deployment parameter '**keys_ServiceManaged_name**' is null. Please specify 
the value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.
At C:\Users\longoj\Downloads\ExportedTemplate-DEEAResourceGroup\deploy.ps1:110 char:9
+         New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resour ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet*

If set the value in parameters.json:

```
"advisors_DropIndex_name": {
    "value": "DropIndex"
},
```

the script validation moves on to the next parameter, and there are a lot of them. So it looks like the template.json file's defaultvalue parameter is being ignored.

I am using:

```
Version           : 5.1.2
Name              : Azure
Author            : Microsoft Corporation
PowerShellVersion : 3.0
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **defaultValue** will be used in case there is no value provided during deployment (e.g. parameters.json).

In your case, you are providing that parameter value, which is **null** and it is invalid per error message (e.g. InvalidDeploymentParameterValue).

Remove the entire following code from the parameters.json file if you want the default value to be applied.

```
"advisors_DropIndex_name": {
    "value": null
},
```

Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-parameters.

Comment: Correct but counter-intuitive. I expected the files generated by the portal to just work-out of the box.So I deleted all the parameters except the ones I am over-writing -- and it is working. Of course, now I am finding the whole template generation model is crap. You get different templates depending on where they are generated, and what you end up with may or may not work AND needs to be debugged and edited.